# deb installation error: "Could not download all required files"

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, deb, crunchbang

I'm running 64-bit Crunchbang 11 "Waldorf" on Debian Wheezy.

I'm trying to install a [driver for my Epson printer](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=22586&DSCCHK=a46b5329e226e11ba6293fcfdbecbdb8201903d4). The file that I click to download is called `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.2.3-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`.

When I run the package, I get the following error: "Could not download all required files".

How can I resolve this?

Perhaps my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file will be of assistance:

```
## CRUNCHBANG
## Compatible with Debian Wheezy, but use at your own risk.
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main
# deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main

## DEBIAN
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://http.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN SECURITY
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
# deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

deb http://qgis.org/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian wheezy main
```

Comment: I can install the file with no problem on my Debian. Did you run `apt-get update` before installing? How are you installing? `gdebi-gtk` or `dpkg`?

Comment: Strange, I just tried again and it installed just fine! I may have done an `apt-get update` inbetween, but I think I tried it afterwards and it still didn't work. Perhaps it was a network error?

Comment: Perhaps there was a problem with one of the repository servers when you tried and it's been fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install via APT?

```
aptitude install printer-driver-escpr
```

The wheezy version is a bit older but may still do the job.

Comment: Sorry, but I got it to work now, [see my comment](http://superuser.com/questions/612885/deb-installation-error-could-not-download-all-required-files#comment759073_612885).